# Javascript Postfix Notation

Tags: javascript, postfix-notation

I would like help in taking the following expression in postfix notation say, "4 5.2 + 5.7 / 6.1 5--".

First, it must read the expression, then test for operators and then operands and then evaluate the expression. finally, "document.write" every push and pop in separate lines. Help please as I have run out of places to look from YouTube to this site. I don't even know where to begin so a very simple example to help me start will help. I have some JS knowledge but not that versed in it and i could find little help elsewhere for this particular example.

Comment: I am looking for help in JavaScript I think most of the search provides help for Java. If I could find samples of each of the things I mentioned, I am sure I could probably piece it together into the whole thing.

Comment: If you get a generic psuedocode solution, you can easily write in in JavaScript. You don't have to have a complete JavaScript solution written out. This link was for a basic algorithm, 5th on the google search: http://www.smccd.net/accounts/hasson/C++2Notes/ArithmeticParsing.html

Comment: Thanks Chad, but Most of what I have learned so far has been by deconstructing other people's code or code that was written after I asked specifically. I thought after reading the beginning of this site that I should ask specifically for code help. I did not expect "go look at this other page for help" help. i.e., Google. I am frustrated. When I know how to write a specific code, I share it with whomever needs it however simple. So, If you can help me write this, or know of someone, THAT would be even more helpful. I would not be asking otherwise. But, thank you anyway you seem cool.

Answer (score 0):

Consider breaking down the problem into simpler steps.  For example, the original problem statement that you're given, to evaluate the string

```
4 5.2 + 5.7 / 6.1 5 - -
```

is much too hard to do all at once.  It is better to decompose the problem into managable pieces.  One decomposition is:

1. Break the string into tokens.
2. Develop an interpreter that works on the tokens.

This breakdown is the standard approach for solving these kinds of problems.  A book like [PLAI](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/) covers how to do part 2.  Part 2 is not difficult: maintain a stack of numbers.  As you walk the tokens:

1. If you see a number, push it onto the stack.
2. If you see an operator, pop two numbers off the stack, manipulate them with the operator, and push the result back onto the stack.

This process is the heart of an Reverse Polish Notation ([RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)) calculator.

The first problem is also not too difficult if you're willing to play with tools like regular expressions.  A regular expression can detect patterns in strings and separate strings into pieces.  For example, the following example shows how we can split a string into a sequence of words along space boundaries:

```
var s = "hello this is a test";
var pieces = s.split(" ");
```

For your purposes, your string won't always be nicely spaced out, so you need to split along numeric and operator boundaries.  You need to experiment with [regular expression patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to make the tokenization work the way you want it to.

---

The problem you're trying to solve is actually NOT beginner material.  The problem is one given to second-semester students in computer science, folks who have already gone through something like [How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/) or other similar curricula, with the assumption that the student already knows their favorite programming language down **cold**.  If you're unable to write programs without copying-and-pasting examples from others, you don't yet have the background to do the problem.  Do simpler problems first, get the language into your fingers, and then come back to this.

Comment: thank you. Despite me being a beginner, I agree but our professor says we must do the research to find out how to do this. I also agree with the smaller bites of work. I have however, finished this through copying and pasting parts from other programs. I am not fully satisfied how it looks but it works and that is good for me. I just can't make it divide. Can I post my code and see if you can see where the division error is?

Comment: Never mind. I got it to divide now. Now, all I need it to make it show a border every time it "document.writes"